# Open external links in new tab

Tags: 7, theming

I am using the Bootstrap theme for Drupal 7. I want to open all external links in new tab. For this there are some contribute modules available. But I want to do it in programmatically. When I searched I found this but it is not working for me. Is there any other hook to do this?

This is the code I am using.

```
function mytheme_links($variables) {
  dpm($variables);
  $variables['options']['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
}
```

Comment: Do you want all links to be opened in a new tab or just only the external links? The code you wrote doesn't even check if a link is internal or external.

Comment: Secondly, why don't you use the module?

Comment: Only external links to be open in new tab@ЕлинЙ.

Comment: Then you should find a way to distinguish the external links in a menu from the internal ones. If you use the module [External Links](https://drupal.org/project/extlink) you don't need to find your own way. Why don't you want to use that module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this *js based* code;

```
Drupal.behaviors.externalMenu = function(context, settings) {
    $('#your_menu_id').attr('target', '_blank');
};
```

Comment: I want all external links to open in new tab. Also can we do it in drupal way using preprocess functions@Adi

Comment: This js based code is also Drupal way. Why do you think it is not?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal doesn't pass any `$variables['options']` to that theme function. That is clear from the documentation for [`theme_links()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_links/7).

Since you just want to add an attribute, and not alter the output of a theme function, you just need to implement a theme preprocess function.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_links(&$variables) {
  $links = $variables['links'];
  if (count($links) > 0) {
    foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
      if (url_is_external($link['href'])) {
        $links[$key]['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
      }
    }
    $variables['links'] = $links;
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer, too, doesn't distinguish the links if they're external or not.

Comment: It is not working @kiamlaluno

Comment: @Vamsi I am sorry: I missed the part about external links. I updated my answer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno still link opens in same tab

Comment: @Vamsi Right... Because `$variables['links']` was not updated.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I have pasted the above code in template.php and changed mytheme to my theme name and cleared cache. Still it is not opening in new tab

Answer (score 0):

Try `url_is_external()` function to determine if link is internal or external.

Your code could be something like below:

```
function mytheme_links($variables) {
  $link = $variables['options'];
  if (url_is_external($link)) {
    $variables['options']['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Drupal 7 doesn't pass any `$variables['options']`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution which works as expected. This is the code I have used

```
      $('a').not('[href*="mailto:"]').each(function () {
        var isInternalLink = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
        if ( ! isInternalLink.test(this.href) ) {
          $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
        }
      });
```

which opens the external links in new tab. Place the code in your custom js file